# ¿Cuantos procesos soporta un webserver multi-procesos?

Tags: python, python-2.7, websocket

Tengo un server que debe responder a multiples PCs al tiempo, pero algunos les responde a otros no. Algunas veces sale un alert con la frase : "Bad Gateway".

Esto me llevo a suponer a que el server no es capaz de recibir muchas peticiones, o se sobrecarga.

Añado que utilizo el metodo ThreadedHTTPServer.

Aqui mi codigo:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Autor: Diego Lopez

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import SocketServer
import json
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import signal
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn
import threading

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
       self._set_headers()
       self.wfile.write("<html><body><h1>hi!</h1></body></html>")

    def do_HEAD(self):
       self._set_headers()

   def do_POST(self):
       # Doesn't do anything with posted data
       content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length']) # <--- Gets the 
       size of data
       post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length) # <--- Gets the data itself
       self._set_headers()
       try:
           data_string = json.loads(post_data)
       except:
           self.wfile.write('{"error" : "JSON"}')
           return

       placa = str(data_string["placa"])
       placa = placa.encode("utf8")
       print post_data

       scraping(placa,self)


class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""      


def scraping(placa,self):
    #Aqui realizo una operacion de scraping que me limito en mostrar.
    self.wfile.write('{"estado" : "activo"}')
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('', 8888), S)
    print 'Starting server, use <Ctrl-C> to stop'
    server.serve_forever()
```

Pero no se exactamente que pasa, por eso les pregunto :

¿Cuantos procesos soporta un webserver escrito en python?
¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No existe un límite como tal, la capacidad va a depender de en gran medida de tu sistema. El scraping con selenium según que condiciones puede ser una sobrecarga muy importante.   Por cierto, no estas usando procesos, usas hilos (`ThreadingMixIn`), por lo que estas limitado a un único núcleo de CPU en la práctica por culpa del GIL. Para usar multiprocesos debes usar `ForkingMixIn`.

Comment: Me recomiendas usar ForkingMixIn en mi trabajo como tal? @FJSevilla